# Would adding an additional prompt for 'game identification' questions encourage users to provide more information?

Tags: discussion, game-identification, new-users, tag-warning-request

I've been on a number of SE sites for a while now but this is my first post on a Meta. If this has already been suggested before, I'm happy to recind the question.

Game identification questions are considered off-topic unless examples of screenshots, audio or video are provided. A similar rule is in place on the anime stackexchange for identification without more than a simple description. Despite the tag itself containing a warning on what is required for a *'game-identification'* question to be considered on-topic, multiple posts are made - usually by new users - who do not provide the required information and subsequently don't get their answers. I recently commented on a post (which has since been deleted), asking if the user could provide these details. He/she said that they 'did not realise this' and from the preview left in my inbox, was proceeded by a passive-aggressive remark. From previous posts, the tag's warning seems to be often overlooked and the abundance of closed / negatively voted previous posts provide no suggestion to some that such posts ought to be fleshed out a little more.

My questions are:

- Has the community experimented with the idea of adding an additional unskippable prompt before posting questions with this tag? Something along the lines of *"Game Identification questions are considered off-topic unless examples of video, audio or screenshots are provided. Are you sure you have these?"*
- Would adding such a prompt make any difference?
- Were such measures ever implemented and removed afterwards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we add a tag warning to \[game-identification\]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/should-we-add-a-tag-warning-to-game-identification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that their descriptions need to be fleshed out some more; it's that we don't identify anything from pure memory.  No amount of detail will change that.

SE has experimented with a lot of different ways to put information in front of people, especially new users.  The takeaway that we've seen is that users just don't read, and you can't make them.  They'll press whatever they have to, scroll down without reading, whatever it takes, to bypass the screen.  Their focus isn't on learning how we work; it's on asking their question.

So, to answer your questions:

- Has the community experimented with the idea of adding an additional unskippable prompt before posting questions with this tag? - No, because we can't even guarantee they'll use the right tag.  Even if they do, see above; they won't care.
- Would adding such a prompt make any difference? - Not even a little.
- Were such measures ever implemented and removed afterwards? - To my knowledge, no.  Mostly because previous experiments on SE have shown that they don't get read.

I invite you to create a new account, and try asking a new question.  New users are provided with a wealth of information prior to first asking.  I don't think the vast majority read it.

Comment: My bad; when I said the descriptions ought to be fleshed out more, I was referring to supplementing them with pictures, video etc.