# Should we add a tag warning to [game-identification]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, game-identification, tag-warning-request

As [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15994/163757) discussed, and as a [Stack Exchange Community Manager suggested](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15994/tag-warnings-looking-for-suggestions-of-tags-that-often-got-low-quality-questio#comment48808_15994), this question serves to ask the community the following:

##### Should we add a tag warning to the [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tag?

Comment: I feel this one is a no-brainer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**, we should add a warning to the [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tag.  It is one of the most commonly seen questions that fail to meet the requirements defined in the tag.

Piggy-backing off the [original post's answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15997/163757) for this tag:

"*The warning should replicate the tag info, which provides enough information, but typically is not read by new users*"

Suggested warning text (open to suggestions):

> Only ask **if you have a screenshot, video, or audio clip from the game you want to identify**. The only game identification questions allowed on this site are those asking to identify games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or otherwise where an unknown game appears - not from a description of what you can recall from memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

Comment: I would strongly suggest making *"screenshot, video, or audio clip"* bold in there. It's a psychology thing, there's a lot of things on any given SE page that try to draw attention themselves.

Comment: @MiG good idea.

Comment: We implemented a tag warning on [tag:game-identification] with the text you've provided in this answer, verbatim.

Comment: For those curious, this is the warning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr1Xt.png